# cp - copying and keeping different version

Tags: bash, cp

[image: screen shot of the terminal]

How to copy all .aze files that have different contents into folder3 ?
The screen show what I don't want to do.
What I want to get close is to have in folder 3, file1(1).aze and file1(2).aze (and other .aze)

I want the two version of file1.aze in folder 3.

I use

```
find -name "*.aze" -exec cp {} folder3/ \;
```

I tried adding `--parents` but it also keep file that have same contents and same name. (I only want one copy of each version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your desired result is. Do you want both `folder1/file1.aze` and `folder2/file1.aze` to go directly into `folder3`?

```
`-folder3
  +-file1.aze        # <-- from folder1
  `-file1.aze        # <-- from folder2
```

That isn't possible without renaming at least one of the files. Something like this may work for renaming files with sequential numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

extension=".aze"
filename="$(basename "$1")"
basename="$(basename "$1" "$extension")"
dst="folder3"

[ "$(dirname "$1")" == "$dst" ] && exit 0

n=0
while [ -f "$dst/$filename" ]; do
  filename="${basename}($((++n)))$extension"
done

cp "$1" "$dst/$filename"
```

Run it like this:

```
find -name "*.aze" -exec ./filecopy.sh {} \;
```

What do you want to achieve anyway? For keeping multiple versions of the same file, you'd better use a revision control system like [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what I'd like to achieve. I know they have to be renamed like file1(1).aze and file1(2).aze. It's just that i've got a lot of .odt files in a really complex tree, it's a big mess and I just want to get every .odt without missing anything because of they got the same name. I'll only do this once.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything worked, awesome bash script ! Only things it can't do is that it checks if file with same name aren't the same. But I'm pretty sure there's another command that can help me have only unique files. Good evening

Comment: @user2178064 Use `diff` to check if two files are different.

Comment: Yep, I've found that command, but i've got hundred of files. Oh and any idea why in the final folder I found some files with name like that : "math 4(5)(1).odt" and "math(5).odt" and all the other math(1...5).odt. Implementing an if condition in the script look too hard. I'll do it manualy I think.